# Splitting an string into a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string with two different delimiters (| and ~). I want to first split based on one delimiter (|) then loop through the results and split those results by the second delimiter (~). From there I want to take the three values form the second split and assign them to labels on my page.

The problem I am having is with the code below I can only get item[0], for item[1] and item[2] I get an index out of bounds error.

I am not sure where I have gone wrong here and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
    int rowNumber = 1;
    foreach (string itemArray in ItemList.Text.Split('|'))
    {
        Label tbCM = (Label)FindControl("CM" + rowNumber);
        Label tbCode = (Label)FindControl("Code" + rowNumber);
        Label tbAmt = (Label)FindControl("Amt" + rowNumber);
        HtmlTableRow trItem = (HtmlTableRow)FindControl("trRow" + rowNumber);

        string[] item = itemArray.Split('~');
        tbCM.Text = item[0].TrimStart(',');
        tbCode.Text = item[1];
        tbAmt.Text = item[2];

        trItem.Style.Add("display", "block");

        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;            
    }
```

Comment: What format is the input string in?

Comment: An example of a string you are trying to split in this manner would be very helpful.

Comment: Apart from an actual answer on your split-issue, i assume that you're doing something wrong. Is this string some kind of ViewState replacement? Maybe there is a better/more readable approach.

Comment: Agree with Tim Schmelter - you should look for a more robust solution, such as serializing an object to json or viewstate or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check for bad input:

```
    string[] item = itemArray.Split('~');

    if (item.Length == 3)
    {
        tbCM.Text = item[0].TrimStart(',');
        tbCode.Text = item[1];
        tbAmt.Text = item[2];
    }
    else
    {
        // handle bad input
    }
```

BTW:  You can also do multiple splits in one call:

```
  string[] Items = itemArray.Split(new char[] {'~', ','});
```

Comment: I agree; it never hurts to practice defensive coding.

Answer (score 0):

`index out of bounds error` means that you accessing the array with the index which exceeds it's size. 
That means that you  **probbably** have an input string like this.

```
"aaaa~|ccccc~dddd"
```

First splitting it by "|" you get

```
{"aaaa~"}, {"cccc~dddd"}
```

and after if you split it by "~", you will get

```
{"aaaa"}, {"cccc","dddd"}
```

but you have splitted array with `Lenght == 1` (in first case).
As it's not absolutely clear from the question the *real* state of the program, it's just a **guess** of what could happen.

So to resolve this, you need

- or fix your input string format (if it's mandatory fformat)
- or fix your algorithm, in order to be able to handle not "good formatted" strings
- or both of them

The last thing: Consider of using the `Split(new char{'|', '~'})` overload and split the stirng in "one shot".

Hope this helps.